# Haskell Global var inside loop

Tags: haskell

This is one of my functions which involve a few other more.

```
main' :: IO ()
main' = do putStr "Enter a string: "
           yx <- getLine
           let a = chunks yx
           let counter = (length . concat . map pairToList) a
           let c = 0
           let loop = do
               let b = a !! c
               let kk = xx b
               let c = c + 1
               let q = oncemore kk
               when (c /= (counter))  loop
           pp(q)
```

**My question will be at the bottom in bold**

I'll let here the rest of the functions expecting new ways to sort my problem. At the end I have an image of how the final output should looks like.
(I'm repeating the above code in the bottom one)

```
module Bigtext where
import Char
import Hugs.Prelude
import Data.List
import Control.Monad

cap :: Char -> Char
cap  c = if c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' then chr (ord c - 32) else c

letter' :: Char -> [String]

pp :: [String]->IO()
pp = putStr . concatMap (++"\n")

letter' 'A' = [" AA ",
               "A  A",
               "AAAA",
               "A  A",
               "A  A"]

letter' 'B' = ["BBB ",
               "B  B",
               "BBB ",
               "B  B",
               "BBB "]

letter' 'C' = [" CCC",
               "C   ",
               "C   ",
               "C   ",
               " CCC"]

letter' 'D' = ["DDD ",
               "D  D",
               "D  D",
               "D  D",
               "DDD "]

letter' 'E' = ["EEEE",
               "E   ",
               "EEE ",
               "E   ",
               "EEEE"]

letter' 'F' = ["FFFF", 
               "F   ", 
               "FFF ", 
               "F   ", 
               "F   "]

letter' 'G' = [" GGG ", 
               "G    ", 
               "G  GG", 
               "G   G", 
               " GGG "]

letter' 'H' = ["H  H", 
               "H  H", 
               "HHHH", 
               "H  H", 
               "H  H"]

letter' 'I' = ["III", 
               " I ", 
               " I ", 
               " I ", 
               "III"]

letter' 'J' = ["    J", 
               "    J", 
               "    J", 
               "J   J", 
               " JJJ "]

letter' 'K' = ["K  K", 
               "K K ", 
               "KK  ", 
               "K K ", 
               "K  K"]

letter' 'L' = ["L   ",
               "L   ",
               "L   ",
               "L   ",
               "LLLL"]

letter' 'M' = ["M   M",
               "MM MM",
               "M M M",
               "M   M",
               "M   M"]

letter' 'N' = ["N   N",
               "NN  N",
               "N N N",
               "N  NN",
               "N   N"]

letter' 'O' = [" OOO ",
               "O   O",
               "O   O",
               "O   O",
               " OOO "]

letter' 'P' = ["PPPP ",
               "P   P",
               "PPPP ",
               "P    ",
               "P    "]

letter' 'Q' = [" QQQ  ",
               "Q   Q ",
               "Q   Q ",
               "Q  QQ ",
               " QQQQQ"]

letter' 'R' = ["RRRR ",
               "R   R",
               "RRRR ",
               "R R  ",
               "R  RR"]

letter' 'S' = [" SSS ",
               "S    ",
               " SSS ",
               "    S",
               "SSSS "]

letter' 'T' = ["TTTTTT",
               "  TT  ",
               "  TT  ",
               "  TT  ",
               "  TT  "]

letter' 'U' = ["U   U",
               "U   U",
               "U   U",
               "U   U",
               " UUU "]

letter' 'V' = ["V     V",
               "V     V",
               " V   V ",
               "  V V  ",
               "   V   "]

letter' 'W' = ["W     W",
               "W     W",
               "W  W  W",
               " W W W ",
               "  W W  "]

letter' 'X' = ["X   X",
               " X X ",
               "  X  ",
               " X X ",
               "X   X"]

letter' 'Y' = ["Y   Y",
               " Y Y ",
               "  Y  ",
               "  Y  ",
               "  Y  "]

letter' 'Z' = ["ZZZZZ",
               "   Z ",
               "  Z  ",
               " Z   ",
               "ZZZZZ"]

letter' ' ' = ["      ",
               "      ",
               "      ",
               "      ",
               "      "]

letter' c = letter' (cap c)

letter :: Char -> IO()
letter c = pp(letter' (cap c))

zipAll :: [[String]] -> [String]
zipAll = map unwords . transpose

chunk :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunk _ [] = []
chunk n xs = first : chunk n rest where (first, rest) = splitAt n xs

splitSkip :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitSkip n xs = transpose $ chunk n xs

chunks yx = words yx

pairToList :: a -> [a]
pairToList x = [x]

xx b = zipAll (map (letter' . head) (splitSkip (length b) b))

type MyString = [String]

oncemore :: MyString -> MyString
oncemore kk = kk ++ kk

main' :: IO ()
main' = do putStr "Enter a string: "
           yx <- getLine
           let a = chunks yx
           let counter = (length . concat . map pairToList) a
           let c = 0
           let loop = do
               let b = a !! c
               let kk = xx b
               let c = c + 1
               let q = oncemore kk
               when (c /= (counter))  loop
           pp(q)
```

This is the expected output:

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDm7w.png)

**This is where I am at the moment**

```
main' :: IO ()
main' = do putStr "Enter a string: "
           yx <- getLine
           let a = chunks yx
           let counter = (length . concat . map pairToList) a
           let c = 0
           let loop c = do
               let c' = c + 1
               let b = a !! (c'-1)
               let kk = xx b
               if c' /= counter
                  then return kk
               else loop c'
           **kk <- loop c**
           pp(kk)
```

In the line **kk <- loop c** if I change c for a number, its possible to get a word (depending of how many words your input has) the problem is: **How do I print all the index's?? for example if I have 3 words, how do I print it out without hard code?**

Sorry about my english...
And thank you for your time.

Comment: Haskell has no "global" state. So you can not really set `q`, etc. furthermore your code looks very imperative, this is usually not how fuctional programming works.

Comment: Note that `let c = c + 1` is infinitely recursive, so you'll get an error or an infinite looo when you try to use it.

Comment: Usually functional programming implies that (most) functions are pure. This means that functions can not depend on global state: everything needs to be passed explicitly, and for the same input, a function should always produce the same output.

Comment: About let c = c + 1 : The way I right that it will exite the loop once it reaches the same value as counter. (I'm not sure.)

Comment: Willem Van Onsem
I am new in this type of programming language. I can see you know what you are explaining and I want to thanks for that.
Could you give me any help with this? How would you do to get the final result? (I am creating an image to upload)

Comment: You also never actually run your loop.

Comment: @RobertoLopes I don't think you understood me. I'm not saying that `loop` is infinitely recursive. I'm saying that `c` is. Any use of `c` will lead to an error or infinite loop. Guaranteed. It doesn't matter what the rest of the program says; that line by itself is infinitely recursive.

Comment: @sepp2k Omg, you right... I forgot to run the loop function... Thanks.

Comment: I don't really know much of this language... I'm learning this from 5 days now... I'm thinking of split my main' function and treat each step on a side and at the end run all of them.
Is this an option? (good or bad?)

Comment: The bottom line here is that your code is very ill-suited to Haskell right now. I suggest asking a question more of the form "I'm trying to solve X problem using functional programming. Where am I going wrong?" Because I'm having trouble telling what the objective of your code is right now.

Comment: My question was how to turn the variable q into global. that variable is shown at the first peace of code.
But after the first comments, I think I'll need to change my function entirely.

Comment: @RobertoLopes Yes, I would probably recommend that. You're trying to write C/Java-style code in Haskell, and it simply doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo So, split everything might be the way?

Comment: Try to write, in English words, what your program's intended behavior is. Then edit that intended behavior into your question (or ask a new question). Then you should get some good answers, even if they are "scrap your solution and try this other cool thing".

Comment: Note that `letter'` will go into an infinite loop on symbols like `?`, you can use guards in your `cap` function to do that in a nice readable way.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe I am aware of that, this function will be mainly for letters. After I solve all the problems I just need to add the rest of the asc II
But thank you for your comment. I could have forgotten...

Comment: @RobertoLopes I can highly recommend http://learnyouahaskell.com/

Comment: @robertolopes `Char` is not only ASCII you can have fun stuff like `π` or `€` in your `String`s

Comment: Ok ok, I only need letters for this coursework xD

Comment: `let fresult = fresult ++ result` is another infinite loop, similarly to your previous `let c = c+1`. It has the same form, essentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole thing can be accomplished with the following:

```
module Main where

import Data.List (transpose)
import Data.Char (ord, chr, toUpper)

pp :: [String] -> IO ()
pp = putStr . unlines

letter :: Char -> [String]
{- letter definitions go here -}
-- anything else gets a square of ?'s
letter _ =  ["?????",
             "?   ?",
             "?   ?",
             "?   ?",
             "?????"]

bigify :: String -> [String]
bigify = map unwords . transpose . map (letter . toUpper)

main :: IO ()
main = do putStr "Enter a string: "
          getLine >>= pp . concatMap bigify . words
```

In `main`, we get a line of text, break it into words, and for each word, `bigify` the word into lines, concatenate the lines, and `pp` the whole thing.

The `bigify` function maps each character in its word argument, passing each character to `toUpper` and then `letter`, which converts it to a list of lines for the upper-case version of that character.  The result is a list with an element per character where each element is a list of lines for that character.  This is `transpose`d into a list with an element per line where each element is a list of pieces of each character for that line.  These elements are joined with `unwords` to form a list of lines.

Comment: Thank you,
I tried your answer and it works perfectly! I only changed letter for letter' to use my old letters.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell variables aren't “variable” in the sense that programmers usually interpret the word, namely, they aren't mutable. Basically, any Haskell variable is just a local constant. Hence your loop construct doesn't make sense, namely

```
       let c = 0
       let loop = do
            ...
            let c = c + 1
            when (c /= counter) loop
```

does not work at all.

- You don't actually enter the loop, you merely define what the loop would be.
- If you did enter the loop, you'd badly trip over the `let c = c + 1`. This does not modify the existing `c`, instead it just defines a completely separate variable `c` which, because it's in a narrower scope, *shadows* the former `c = 0`. This shadowing binding is even used in the definition itself, i.e. to calculate `c` the runtime needs to know the value of `c`, to which it needs to calculate `c`, to which... and so on.

What you actually want there is

```
       let c = 0
       let loop c = do
            ...
            let c' = c + 1
            when (c' /= counter) $ loop c'
       loop 0  -- actually invoke the loop, starting from 0.
```

But even so, this loop doesn't really accomplish anything – you merely define some local variables in each iteration, but never actually do anything of lasting impact with them.

You *could* in each iteration commit some actual `IO` action, such as printing out a single big letter. You could also yield some result from the loop, which seems to be what you're asking in this question. For instance, to broadcast the last “state” of `q` to the outside, you'd need to replace the `when` (which shortcuts to `return ()` if the condition is not fulfilled) with

```
       let loop c = do
            let q = ...
            let c' = c + 1
            if c' == counter
             then return q
             then loop c'
       q <- loop 0
```

But I dispute that this is sensible; instead, a much better approach is to concatenate all the letters still in list form (that doesn't require any ugly index/length juggling nor any IO or explicit loops, just `map` and `concat`), and then printing the entire result in one clean `putStr`.